# Fastest approach for geopandas (reading and spatialJoin)

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, geopandas

I have about a million rows of data with lat and lon attached, and more to come. Even now reading the data from SQLite file (I read it with pandas, then create a point for each row) takes a lot of time.

Now, I need to make a spatial joint over those points to get a zip code to each one, and I really want to optimise this process.

So I wonder: if there is any relatively easy way to parallelize those computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the most convenient solution in my case is to use pandas.read_SQL function with specific chunksize parameter. In this case, it returns a generator of data chunks, which can be effectively feed to the mp.Pool().map() along with the job; 
In this (my) case job consists of 1) reading  geoboundaries, 2) spatial joint of the chunk 3) writing the chunk to the database.

Comment: Update: right now there is a raw beta of Dask-Geopandas that theoretically could parallelize everything automatically

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have already implemented GeoPandas and are still finding difficulties?
you can improve this by further hashing your coords data. similar to how google hashes their search data. Some databases already provide support for these types of operations (eg mongodb). Imagine if you took the first (left) digit of your coords, and put each set of cooresponding data into a seperate sqlite file. each digit can be a hash pointing to the correct file to look for. now your lookup time has improved by a factor of 20 (`range(-9,10)`), assuming your hash lookup takes minimal time in comparison

Comment: yeah, I am using geopandas wth rtree. Thank you for sharing on hashing - this sounds good. However, thing is, I have access to a cluster of machines, and use it for other computations - however, I realised that I have no idea how to implement parallelisation in pandas. 
Shall I split the dataframe to a generator and run tasks in simple mp.pool?

Comment: i do not know of a parallelization process for database lookup/join processes. to implement my suggestion, create a dictionary with keys range(-9,10), and values pointing to the files containing the corresponding data. this way to lookup the right number you have to look through less data, and so will make it faster to do joins also

Answer (score 0):

This method is *completely dependent* on your spatial scale, but one way you might parallelize your join would be to subdivide your polygons into subpolygons and then offload the work to separate threads in separate cores. This [geopandas r-tree](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/) tutorial demonstrates that technique, subdividing a large polygon into many small ones and intersecting each with a large set of points. But again, this only works if your spatial scale is appropriate: ie, a few polygons and a lot of points (such as a few zip code polygons and millions of points in and around them).